# Getting XML malformed error once I just create a target in Apigee

Tags: apigee

> Server Error.
>   javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException - with linked exception:
>   [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 22;
>   columnNumber: 2; The markup in the document following the root element
>   must be well-formed.]

XML is well formed when I checked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. Change all & to & and you're good. The XML Parser used by Apigee wrongly interprets the & as a functional character.